# JsonSlurper generating different result between single-quoted and double-quoted input

Tags: json, groovy

I want to convert a String to json and using

`JsonSlurper.parseText("{'name' : 'robel'}")` is Throwing Exception.

I tried changing  it to

`JsonSlurper.parseText('{"name" : "robel"}')`

and it works fine. All i did to the first code is substitute the the single cote with double cote and vice versa .can some one tell me why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: please add the error for reference. and isn't that two times the same?

Comment: If there are single quotes, it is not JSON. See http://json.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Both things in your question are the same?

Json requires double quotes

You need an instance of JsonSlurper, and double quotes in your json:

```
new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"name" : "robel"}')
```

Comment: sorry i edited the question.and the thing is i have a very large file which contains json datas with this format {'name' : 'robel'} .so i need to convert this into json

Comment: and the second thing is i want to know why this is happening as i am able to use both single and double cote's in groovy for a string. what makes this condition special

Comment: The json standard. It says double quotes. What you have (with single quotes) isn't json

Comment: In what you just wrote, you don't need the "RELAX" slurper, so I'm assuming you mean it worked for when you used single-quotes in the json?

Comment: JsonSlurper.setType(RELAX).parseText("{'name' : 'robel'}") did the trick for me